# Need to push message in AWS SQS using JMETER or LoadRunner (role based authentication)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, performance-testing, amazon-sqs, loadrunner

I have a requirement to push message in AWS SQS using JMeter or LoadRunner.

I have gone through [AWS Query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-making-api-requests-xml.html) this link which will create a Query API, but it requires AWS Access Key ID which is restricted in my organization.

Is there any other way or using role-based authentication we can send message in SQS?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available with JMeter plugins manager called `awsmeter`

Repo: https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/awsmeter

You can clone, modify according to your needs

For LoadRunner: You can write your own login using the provided sdk from the AWS

Comment: Will it work without having ACCESS KEY?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the request in any case needs to be authenticated somehow. If [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler along with [AWS Signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) doesn't fit your needs you can consider using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) for sending the request.

Example code (copied and pasted from [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/sqs/src/main/java/com/example/sqs/SendMessages.java)):

```
SqsClient sqsClient = SqsClient.builder()
    .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
    .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
    .build();
sendMessage(sqsClient, queueName, message);
sqsClient.close();
```

Again if [ProfileCredentialsProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/profile/ProfileCredentialsProvider.html) is not something you can use (however I fail to see why) you can choose [any other](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) or come up with your own.

Answer (score 1):

So, to paraphrase my understanding.   You want to use Amazon SQS service, but you do not have the access key so you are looking for a security workaround to use the queue service.  Is this correct?

Have you considered a local installation (or EC2 installation) of RabbitMQ?

Comment: First statement is Correct. Would you share how local installation can help to push SQS message via LR or JMETER?

Comment: web_custom_request() in LR with the sample provided by Amazon.  But, you will need the key.

Comment: KEY is the restriction here! Any other approach you have?

Comment: I do not have a security workaround for AWS.  Even if I did I wouldn't share it with you as it would be worth millions to the hacker market.  Either have the key shared with you by the admin or seek a different option.